# Explain why the convective derivative of the position vector is the velocity.

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics

Can someone please explain why the convective derivative of the position is the velocity. It's not very obvious to me from the definition.

Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of the convective derivative?

Answer (score 0):

$
\renewcommand\vec\mathbf
$

I assume by convective derivative you mean [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvectiveDerivative.html):
$$
  \frac D{Dt} = \frac\partial{\partial t} + \vec v\cdot\nabla
$$
where $\vec v = \vec v(x)$ is the velocity field and $\vec x$ is the position vector. The key fact is that
$$
  (\vec a\cdot\nabla)f(\vec x) = f(\vec a)
$$
for any *linear* function $f$ and vector $\vec a$. This is particularly intuitive when  $f(\vec x) = \vec x$ is the identity function:
$$
  (\vec a\cdot\nabla)\vec x = \vec a,
$$
which is saying that the change of $\vec x$ as $\vec x$ varies in the direction $\vec a$ is just $\vec a$. Now in the convective derivative, the velocity $\vec v$ is not being differentiated; it's just being used like an ordinary vector. Hence
$$
  \frac{D\vec x}{Dt}
    = \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial t} + (\vec v\cdot\nabla)\vec x
    = \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial t} + \vec v.
$$
We're almost there, but we still have that time derivative, which we want to be zero. There are two possible interpretations of $\vec x$ here:

1. $\vec x = \vec x(t)$ is the path of a particle as time varies.
2. $\vec x = (x, y, z)$ where $x, y, z, t$ are considered independent variables.

In interpretation (1) we need $\vec x(t) = \text{const}$, but in interpretation (2) we always have $\partial\vec x/\partial t = 0$ whence
$$
  \frac{D\vec x}{Dt} = \vec v.
$$